# Performing Spatial join with polygons using st_join in R?

Tags: r, polygon, spatial-join

I want to join 2 partly overlapping polygons in R the same way I'm doing it in ArcGIS Desktop . In ArcGIS Desktop I am doing it like this: Analysis toolbox - Overlay toolset - Spatial Join. The rows are matched based on their spatial locations. I want to "merge" all the columns of polygon1 with columns of polygon2 but only for rows (polygons) that exist in polygon1.

Unfortunately I can't give a reproducible example right now. This is what I did:

```
result_r <- st_join(x = polygon1, y = polygon2, join = st_intersects, left = TRUE, largest = TRUE)
```

That produced the warning: `attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries`. I used `largest = TRUE` because otherwise there would have been too many duplicated rows.

The ArcGIS Desktop result has the same number of rows as the R result. But when I check the number of rows for a certain condition, then the R result has more rows than ArcGIS Desktop :

```
result_arcgis <- readOGR(dsn = "path", layer = "result_arcgis")
result_arcgis <- st_as_sf(result_arcgis)
nrow(result_arcgis[which(!is.na(result_arcgis$colum_x)),])
# 30 rows
nrow(result_r[which(!is.na(result_r$colum_x)),])
# 51 rows
```

Obviously `st_join` isn't the same as the described ArcGIS Desktop procedure.

What is the correct R function to reproduce the ArcGIS Desktop procedure?

Comment: I assume you used Join Operation=JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE and Match Option=INTERSECT in your Spatial Join in ArcGIS?  Really need a reprex to figure out.  With some toy data, I find if you use `largest=TRUE` in your `st_join` in R, you get correct result assuming for a one-to-many polygon overlap you just want to return the overlap of greatest area.  In my check with some toy data, ArcGIS Desktop is not doing this correctly with Spatial Join of polygons.